# How do you expose the Javascript/Jquery behaviours so that it can be modified or extended from outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

For instance I have function that hides some element , but I want to expose that behaviour so that script outside can act after element is hidden

```
(function($){ 
   function hide_element() { 
      $('#my_element').hide(); 
   }
})(jQuery);
```

I want to make this API easily extensible by other scripts. Is there any best practice to achieve this.

Comment: You can create your own global unique namespace. `var MY={}` and share stuff in there.

Comment: Assuming the code above is in the global namespace, it's exposed via `hide_element`. It would only be hidden if you specifically went out of your way to hide it.

Comment: Its not within the global namespace , let me modify the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you are trying to achieve is the good way of writing softwares by exposing your API for outside world to act on it. I do that all the time while I write Drupal modules and Javascript and it makes really easy to extend the existing behaviours in the future. So its very good practice to expose you API as much as possible. If you are using Jquery you can achieve this behaviour using  Jquery trigger API http://api.jquery.com/trigger/.

For instance, you want to expose your element behaviour once the element is completely hidden. Then you can do it like this:

```
function hide_element() { 

 $('#my_element').hide(function() { 
    $(this).trigger('elementHidden'); 
    //if you want to pass arguments 
    //$(this).trigger('elementHidden', [argument1, argument2]); 
 }); 
}
```

This can be extended from outside like this

```
//if no arguments
$('#my_element').on('elementHidden', function () { 
   //they will do their thing

}); 
// if arguments 
$('#my_element').on('elementHidden', function (event, argument1, argument2) { 
   //they will do their thing

});
```

Make sure you have proper documentation over your `hide_element` function that what it is exposing.